# Программное изменение settings.py (django)

Tags: python, django

Вопрос в следующем, у меня есть `development` сервер и `production`.
Некоторый функционал завязан на переменную `PRODUCTION` из `settings.py`.
Как мне при помощи самого питона или через `bash` изменять эту переменную, например, перед выгрузкой на `production`?

Comment: Непонятно чего вы хотите добится. Разных конфигов для production и development?

Comment: Различных значений переменной PRODUCTION. 
PRODUCTION = True - если prod.
PRODUCTION = False - eсли dev.

Comment: Там ниже про settings_local уже ответили. это лучший вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте файл `local_settings.py`, в нём прописывайте конфиг для девелоп-сервера и импортируйте его в конце `settings.py`, чтобы перезаписать нужные переменные. А на продакшн просто не выкладывайте этот файл (например, можно не включать его в репозиторий).

Answer (score 2):

Каким образом выгружаешь?

Я, например, использую Fabric и для включени/выклюячения дебага выполняю такой таск

```
@task
def debug(param="on"):
    """Toogle DEBUG variable in local_settings.py"""
    with cd(env.path):
        config_path = 'my_project/local_settings.py'
        if param == "on":
            uncomment(config_path, r'(DEBUG)')
        if param == "off":
            comment(config_path, r'^(DEBUG)')
        execute(restart_webserver)
```

Можешь сделать что-то аналогичное для своей PRODUCTION.

Answer (score 0):

В Django есть переменная `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, в которую можно прописать модуль с конфигурацией: `your_proj.settings`