# Как можно запустить django проект локально без перемещения бд из сервера

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Добрый день, стал интересен один вопрос.

Если у меня есть Django-проект и в настройках DATABASES уже прописана база данных, которой у меня локально в принципе нету. Можно ли туда как-то добавить новую, или как поменять часть кода, чтобы runserver для тестов у меня запускался нормально? Каждый раз менять эту часть кода тоже не хочется, поэтому и спрашиваю :)

Заранее приношу извинения, если вопрос показался слегка глупым

Comment: Гонять тесты на БД продакшена? Ох, очень спорная идея

Comment: Тем не менее просто пропишите в DATABASES параметры подключения к нужной БД да и всё, что мешает? Или у вас конфиги для продакшена и для разработки почему-то никак не разделены?

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, была маленькая ошибка в названиях. Поэтому думал что так нельзя сделать) теперь решилось

Comment: Кстати насчёт разделения: храните все подключения к базам, ключи, пароли и прочие секретики [в конфиге local_settings.py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/251697), который у каждого отдельного компьютера должен быть свой собственный

Comment: Ну и вообще неужели база данных весит настолько много, что скачать её себе хотя бы частично нет возможности?)

Comment: @andreymal да я не хотел морочиться со скачиваением еще ;D
Спасибо за советы